# как сделать HTML-шаблон письма?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка-email

Нужно сделать шаблон письма в html. подскажите пожалуйста как это лучше сделать? с помощью таблицы и внутри тегов прописывать стили или можно с помощью дивов? и можно ли с помощью таблицы бутстрап. или не стоит подключать будстрап?

[image: ВОт такого вида надо сделать. качество конечно не важное, но какое есть.]

Comment: Про flexbox и тем более grid вообще забудьте. Web браузер и email клиент -- разные вещи. Тем более что есть помимо браузера еще десктопные и мобильные email клиенты.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше конечно же использовать таблицы, так как письмо может быть открыто в  почтовых клиентах и браузерах, которые не поддерживают новые версии HTML и CSS так уж получилось что почтовые клиенты используют разные движки и зависли еще в допотопных временах. Табличная вёрстка для Вас будет залогом того, что письмо не развалится и нормально отобразится на всех платформах.

Про подключение отдельного CSS файла вообще можете забыть, так как также могут быть проблемы с отображением и это просто не везде сработает.

Подробнее обо всем это можете почитать [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/252279/), [здесь](https://netology.ru/blog/verstka-mail) и [здесь](https://www.unisender.com/ru/blog/sovety/kak-sverstat-pismo-instruktsiya-dlya-chaynikov/)

Comment: а не подскажите как сделать расстояние между ячейками таблицы как на картинке.  чтобы между цветными фонами было расстояние? border-spacing не работает.

Comment: Можете добавить аттрибут `cellspacing="value"` на Вашу таблицу

Comment: что то не помогает.

Comment: работает только если если сделать order-collapse: separate; и добавить значение в cellspacing. но тогда расстояние между верхними ячейками и нижними больше чем между левыми и правыми ячейками. а как сделать чтобы везде было одинаковое расстояние?